# Where am I going wrong with returning an array from a react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a react function that is a api call ad gets some data, I want to just return the status of that back to the parent component.

Here is my code

Parent component function

```
//this is called via a button with a state passed down to the function
    async function scheduleParent(){
        const returned = await ScheduleChild(data)
        console.log(returned)
    }
```

Child function

```
export default async function ScheduleChild(data){
await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: //myapi,
        data: {data}
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        return(res)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return(err)
    });
```

I am getting undefined when console.log(returned) is called.

Comment: Can you post your full `SchedulePayment` code?

Comment: in React functions which begin with a capital letter must be a React Component and return valid JSX

Comment: Your "Child Function" that looks like it is defined as "ScheduleParent" *does not* `return` anything (the return inside the functions passed to the `.then` and `.catch` don't go all the way out of the function!).

Comment: @AndrewF that's not true - functions you use as a React component must begin with a capital letter (at least at the point at which they're used in JSX, so that they're passed to `createElement` as a _name_ not a _string_) but you can have other functions with leading capital letters that aren't.

Comment: @LucaPizzini Full code posted.

Comment: Neither of the two ScheduleParent functions above return anything.

Comment: @James so what do i do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you a right) it was more correct to say preferable. But I would not recommend capitalizing functions unless it is a class or component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the callback function and not from the `SchedulePayment` . You should add return before your api call in order to work. Or in a nicer way

```
export default async function SchedulePayment(data){
  try {
    const res = axios.post(<api-url>, data)
    return res
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: This still returns undefined

Comment: @matt_roki2 Try to use the `axios.post` function (See edited answer)

Comment: @LucaPizzini That was it! Thank you! only one brave enough to answer rather than just comment as well xD